# Do in While loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I´m all new to programming and I´m learning some basics of Ruby.

Could someone please tell me the difference between these loops.

```
while i < 51
  # ...
end
```

and

```
while i < 51 do
  # ...
end
```

Both of them works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

They are identical. From the [documentation for `while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-while+Loop):

> The *do* keyword is optional.

Same for `until` and `for`.